# How can I merge two Observable Collections, taking only the new and changed items from the new list, and add it to the old list?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a WPF app that uses a DataGrid element that is bound to an ObservableCollection:

```
ObservableCollection<Deployment> deployments = DataAccess.GetDeployments();
datagrid01.ItemsSource = deployments;
```

Here is a Deployment class. A Deployment object represents an Windows installation that is happening out in the field, so things like CurrentTime changes frequently.

```
class Deployment
{
    public string UniqueID { get; set; }        
    public string ComputerName { get; set; }       
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }       
    public string UserName { get; set; }       
    public string TaskSequenceName { get; set; }      
    public string MachineObjectOU { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CurrentTime { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Periodically I want to update DataGrid with any changes to these objects, like the CurrentTime or their Status. Their Status changes to a 3 when they are finished installing, or is a 2 if they are in an error state.

So, I can get a new collection of objects on a timer, but what is the best way to add ONLY the new items from this new collection to the DataGrid, and to CHANGE the existing items who have an updated time, or status, or whatever?

Comment: I personally think checking what records just inserted/changed then add/modify that records into your list taking more longer and complicated than just refresh the list.

Comment: If your data layer is already returning an observable collection, why isn't the UI auto-updating as the collection changes? What is `DataAccess` and why does refreshing it from the database not automatically generate the observable events in the collection for the UI to be updated correctly? Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the question, it's not possible to know what a good answer would be. I do agree that if the collection is not automatically updated on refresh, you might as well just reload the whole thing.

Comment: Reloading the whole collection would end up in re-creating all items in the view. Imagine an ItemsControls with probably a few thousand items, when only a handful of them is added or changed periodically. So for each new item, first check if it is already contained in the deployments collection. If it is, replace or update it, if not, add it.

Comment: I have edited the post to add more information. The UI updating isn't really the problem. I've added objects 'manually' and the UI updates. What has me stumped is the logic to add only the items I want, or to change the existing items that need changes. For some reason this logic stumps me. How do I compare them without using a nested ForEach or something like that?

Comment: @Clemens - That is exactly what I would like some help doing! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .Except() method to filter items from ObservableCollection

```
newRecordings = recordings.Except(_recordingsHidden).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your `ObservableCollection<Deployment>` as property and `Raise` a `property change event` on that using `INotifyPropertyChange` interface. You can then bind this property to your `itemsource` of `DataGrid` in `xaml` itself. Hence any change in your `collection` either from `UI` or from `Database`, whole `list` is refreshed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

A method like shown below should do the job. It does not replace an existing item in the `deployments` collection, but just updates the properties of the item.

In order to make this update the UI, the `Deployment` class would have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` when a property value changes. A simple solution would be to add an `UpdateFrom(Deployment d)` method, which updates all properties and then raises a single PropertyChanged event with `null` as property name (to notify that all properties have changed).

```
using System.Linq;
...

private void UpdateDeployments(IEnumerable<Deployment> changedDeployments)
{
    foreach (var changedDeployment in changedDeployments)
    {
        var deployment = deployments.FirstOrDefault(
            d => d.UniqueID == changedDeployment.UniqueID);

        if (deployment != null)
        {
            deployment.UpdateFrom(changedDeployment);
        }
        else
        {
            deployments.Add(changedDeployment);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your answer, is changedDeployments simply a new collection of deployment objects? Or is it a collection of only NEW or CHANGED deployments?

Comment: It's new and changed objects, of course. That's why the method looks for existing objects by their ID, and then changes a potentially existing object, or adds a new one if the ID wasn't found.